# How to provide a string delimeter in fgetcsv()

Tags: php, fgetcsv

Since my file columns are separated by a tab, I use the following:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
```

But is there a way to deal with a string delimiter as well?

[image]

Comment: Quite unclear what you are trying to ask here. Based on the screenshot you have shown, I'm guessing it might actually be more about how to get the relevant selection from a form ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more one optional parameter:

```
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t", "\"");
```

Here more information [about fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)